# FFmpeg filter to rotate image around point

Tags: ffmpeg, rotation

Does anyone know how to rotate an image to its start point (top-left corner) instead of the center point (default) with the FFmpeg -vf rotate?

In this example I try to rotate a red squared image (**test_sq.png**) **30** degrees from its start point on **in.png** placed at coord **423:259** resulting in **out.png**.

This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.png -pix_fmt bgra -strict experimental -vf movie=test_sq.png scale=279:279 rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:oh=ow [sticker]; [in][sticker] overlay=423:259 [out] -s 1280x720 out.png
```

To visualize it:

[image: Results]

As you can see it rotates from its center point and also clips the original image, not really good.
Anyone have suggestions or ideas how to achieve what i need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your output width and height in the rotate filter are initialized to the input W/H and not auto-calculated to show the entire image after rotation. Use this instead,

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.png -i test_sq.png  \
-filter_complex "[1]scale=279:279,setsar=1,rotate=PI/6:c=none:ow=rotw(PI/6):oh=roth(PI/6)[s];
                 [0][s]overlay=423-w*sin(PI/6)/(sin(PI/6)+cos(PI/6)):259,scale=hd720[out]" \
-map "[out]"-pix_fmt bgra out.png
```

---

For a non-square image,

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.png -i test_sq.png  \
-filter_complex "[1]scale=279:279,setsar=1,rotate=PI/6:c=none:ow=rotw(PI/6):oh=roth(PI/6)[s];
                 [0][s]overlay=423-ih*sin(PI/6):259,scale=hd720[out]" \
-map "[out]"-pix_fmt bgra out.png
```

(You'll have to manually supply the value of `ih` (height of original image).

---

For a non-square image, with a negative rotation

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.png -i test_sq.png  \
-filter_complex "[1]scale=279:279,setsar=1,rotate=-PI/6:c=none:ow=rotw(-PI/6):oh=roth(-PI/6)[s];
                 [0][s]overlay=423:259-iw*sin(PI/6),scale=hd720[out]" \
-map "[out]"-pix_fmt bgra out.png
```

(You'll have to manually supply the value of `iw` (width of original image).

For images without in-built alpha, insert `format=bgra` before the `rotate` filter.

Comment: Since angle is measured in radians, and PI radians = 180 deg, PI/6 = 30*PI/180 = 30 degrees. You can continue to use your earlier notation, e.g. (20*PI/180) for 20 degrees.

Comment: Yes thank you!! (I just noticed that while you were commenting and removed my comment before you commented, sorry), anyway it worked, thanks!

Comment: Now when i tested this with non-square images, it's not working correctly, moving to much to the left, any idea's? for example with scale=333:52. Did you make your answer for square-only images on purpose maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your edit, non-square images work now! One last thing, how to make the position correct for negative rotation degrees aswell? (-20*PI/180) [See here please](https://i.gyazo.com/0cf2f9c3a2ca527dc1fceaddb8a9a899.png) I think it have to move back w/2 and h/2, but I'm not sure how to implement it

Comment: A negative rotation of X degrees is same as positive rotation of (360-X) degrees.

Comment: Ok, but if i run the command with **-35*PI/180** or **325*PI/180** i get both the [same result](https://embed.gyazo.com/0cf2f9c3a2ca527dc1fceaddb8a9a899.png)

Comment: Another example: [see here](https://i.gyazo.com/741d26aa0bdddab78816cbb76b285d83.png)

Comment: Thanks, the format=bgra did the trick for the aplha. Now for the negative degrees, am I reading this correct?: for the overlay: (...) **overlay=423-iw*cos(PI/6)** (...) there you take PI/6, when before you did -PI/6? I am not sure, but because now I got [this result](https://i.gyazo.com/8a0d6a2bd10869de55b191ac5bd0d1ec.png)

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted the topmost point to be the pivot. You want the top-left edge of the original image instead.

Comment: Amazing man, it's all working perfectly now! Wish i could upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation. Anyway thank you again!! You probably saved me 2 days trying to work this out myself

Comment: @Gyan hi, i followed the above command to rotate a view around a certain pivot point, the issue is its still rotating from the center, where as I would like it to be rotated from the topleft, FYI im trying to achieve this is android

Comment: I am trying your code but it does not work when rotation is greater than 90 degrees. Any help??